# Calling python from matlab gives unexpected error

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, openssl

I'm trying to use a function in Python from Matlab2015a. This function is callable from the python interpreter without problems. However, in the matlab interpreter:

```
>> py.file.function()
```

gives the error `Python Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'`.

Simple functions that do trivial things do work from matlab. This one involves networking in other packages and I guess that's somehow confusing matlab. Since I don't think I should be importing anything explicitly in matlab I don't know how to proceed. Any ideas on if this should work?

Another possibility is that matlab uses its own python version without SSL support. However, the python version reported by matlab seems not to back this possibility:

```
>> pyversion

   version: '2.7'
executable: '/usr/bin/python'
   library: 'libpython2.7.so.1.0'
      home: '/usr'
  isloaded: 1
```

Regular HTTP seems to be there:

```
>> py.httplib.HTTPConnection('')
```

ans =

Python HTTPConnection with properties:

```
          port: 80
          host: [1x0 py.str]
          sock: [1x1 py.NoneType]
source_address: [1x1 py.NoneType]
       timeout: [1x1 py.object]

<httplib.HTTPConnection instance at 0x7fc9ac79a0e0>
```

Furthermore, this:

```
>> system('python -c ''import file; file.function()'' ')
```

likewise fails, whereas the exact same line launched from the bash shell works as expected.

Edit: it turns out it works in another machine running ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7.5. The failing one is a 15.10 with 2.7.9. `pyversion` shows the same output (since it doesn't show the third digit in the versioning).

Edit: sys.path reports the same from matlab and python:

```
>>> sys.path # this is python
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

And in matlab:

```
>> py.sys.path

ans =
```

Python list with no properties.

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

Incidentally, the machine that works reports the same path.

Edit: as pointed in the comments, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is somehow related to the problem. However, launching the MATLAB executable directly, bypassing the matlab shell script that modifies LD_LIBRARY_PATH, is not enough: even with a clean value, the failure is the same.

```
>> system('echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH')

ans =

 0

>> py.file.function()
Python Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'
```

Comment: Just to be clear: `file` is a module you wrote, which contains the function `function()`, which in turn has a reference to `HTTPSConnection`? And while `HTTP` works, `HTTPS` doesn't?

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that it is not function() the one that references HTTPSConn, but a third party module called from function(). This third party module is actually pretty simple and does nothing strange, so I don't think it makes any difference for the issue at hand, specially since... (see next comment)

Comment: To add insult to injury, I just tested this in another box and there it works as expected, yet `pyversion` shows the very same output. The working one is an ubuntu 14.04 and the failing one a 15.10, though. I added python versions to the question.

Comment: Compare `sys.path` when starting python directly and when starting it via matlab. I suspect that some environment variable modified by matlab causes your problem.

Comment: Interesting suggestion but they both report the same, I'm adding that info to the question.

Comment: This might have something to do with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, try this system command instead: `system('LD_LIBRARY_PATH= python -c ''import file; file.function()'' ')` If that works then you could do `setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '')` and see if `py.file.function()` works, but I don't know what the other consequences of doing that might be. In any case I would report it to MathWorks technical support.

Comment: Good catch, Thomas, that was it. The problem now is that setenv does not affect py.file.function() syntax, so I can't easily retrieve complex return types...

Comment: I've included the LD_LIBRARY_PATH reported by matlab in the question